# Change file timestamp and display hour instead of year with ls

Tags: files, ls, timestamps

I want to change a file's date to tomorrow 21:00. I used touch, but when I type `ls -l` the year of the file is displayed instead of the hour.

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 ABCD DEF   0 sept. 30  2014 test01
-r-xr-xr-x 1 ABCD DEF   15 sept. 29 09:26 test02
```

Here for example, we can clearly see "2014" but not "21:00". Strange fact, when I perform `touch --date "1 hour ago" test01` it gets displayed correctly, but `touch --date "+1 hour" test01` won't work.
Also, editing the file with emacs and saving it will display the hour instead of the year.

Is that normal? How can I change this behaviour without using parameters in ls nor changing the computer's config? (this is for a challenge)

Answer (score 4):

`ls` has two time display formats:

- For timestamps from the past 6 months: month, day, hour, minute.
- For other timestamps (in the future, or from more than 6 months ago): year, month, day.

The intent is to gain horizontal space and not overwhelm the user with information. Showing “from this year” is more obvious than showing the current year and letting the user notice that it is indeed the current year. The exact time of day rarely matters for very old files. Dates in the future are rare.

[GNU ls](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#Formatting-file-timestamps) has an option `--full-time` to show the full file time (year, month, day, hour, minute, seconds, nanoseconds, timezone offset) regardless of when that time is. You can tune the output format with the option `--time-style`.

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved. The problem is that if the date is in the future, it will display the year instead of the hour.

Here's a simple example: `touch file` and `l` gives

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 ABCD DEF 0 sept. 29 12:01 file
```

whic is normal. No try to change the date to be 15 seconds in the future : `touch --date "+15 seconds" file` and immediately `ls -l`

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 ABCD DEF 0 sept. 29  2014 file
```

And after 15 seconds, the same `ls -l` gives

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 rius_b users 0 sept. 29 12:03 file
```